# Several cursors at once

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

There is a table #Costs `(id,tree_id,date,value)` which holds information for calling sp `exec sp @tree_id,@date,@value output` in order to calculate complex service routine identified by `tree_id`. In order to put @value *cursor* is used.
How to make several cursors working with same `#Costs` table? Many rows in Costs -> cursor with sp runs very long. I cannot turn to inline function or simplify sp logic which has many internal sp callings, temporary inserts/updates etc.
What is the way to do parallel cursors? Can I avoid using Agent jobs or Service Broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have given a question without (IMO) enough detail, ill give a general solution I have used in the past for a similar problem.
Basically I divided the workload into 'buckets', then called several Stored Procedures to run the workload against a given bucket. In my case I used separate powershell instances to execute the SPs because I was moving a lot of log files around, but Agent Jobs would also do the job. Just make sure of course that each 'bucket' can be processed independently.

Performance did increase, but keep an eye out for lock and latch activity and other bottlenecks, in my case I found there was a point of diminishing returns, about 1 core per bucket seemed to work for me.

If you are willing to work with .NET this is another option, if you dont want to set up jobs in Agent: SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: From where did you call powershell instances. Do you have workaround, please?

Comment: I opened several shells and ran from there (monitoring output via the window). however, for something automated and scheduled, I think Agent jobs would be the way to go.